# Launching Chrome Packaged Web App from Website

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, protocols, handler, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged Web app (which is required as it needs to access the Serial Port), and I'd like to be able to launch it from my website (with some data) when I click on a link/button on that website.

It'd be even better if it could detect if the user wasn't running chrome or didn't have the web app installed and could direct them to the right place...

Are there any examples? It seems like an obvious thing to want to do, but I'm really struggling to find anything...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519277/activate-chrome-app-from-web-page for more methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To launch an app you can use [`url_handlers`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/url_handlers.html), a new feature recently [landed](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111422) (should make Chrome 31). You can pass data in the URL.

You can check if an app is already installed, and initiate the install if not, by using the chrome web store's [inline install](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation) functionality.

Comment: This is currently only available in the "dev" channel, not stable.

Comment: Seems stable now. Very simple to implement.

Comment: Unfortunately, url_handlers doesn't work if webpage in incognito mode. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Found a better solution to this problem.

In @Vincent Scheib solution you have to redirect the user to /some/url, or open a new window (that can be actually blocked as popup). All of this it's not so good from an UX aproach.

My solution is to create the app and configure the `externally_connectable`. You have to pass the url domain of the web site that will try to open the app. For example:

```js
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://developer.chrome.com/*"]
}
```

Then, in your packaged app in your **background** script, you can do something like this:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message) {
      if(message.launch){ //This parameter will be passed in sendMessage method below
          chrome.app.window.create("main.html");
      }
});
```

Finally, to trigger the app open you have to send a message using your packaged app id. For example:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("mdoedhlejmepngilmgoenbhmipoclckb", { launch: true });
```

Comment: Is there an idea, how to launch the app from webpage was not pointed to "externally_connectable" ? I want to launch my background app from any webpage ( for example from local network 192.168.1.1 too).

Comment: @AlexeyBleikher I think that with Vincent Scheib answer you could do that