# how to run chrome packaged app from the link on the site?

Tags: google-chrome-app

i know how to run packaged apps from 'chrome://extensions/' section. Is there any way run chrome packaged app from the link on the website ?

Comment: I've recently posted a solution in this SO question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/36772803/1738363](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36772803/1738363)

Answer (score 0):

No. It's launched from the [App Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher).

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that from chrome://extensions, but you can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-apps-developer-too/ohmmkhmmmpcnpikjeljgnaoabkaalbgc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher) app to show a similar extensions and apps list. This one does have a launch link in each one.